# finding the complexity of insertion to avl tree

Tags: insert, binary-search-tree, code-complexity

If I have an empty `avl` tree and I want to insert a set of ordered numbers (1, 2, ... k), why the complexity is `O(k)`.

 thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of a math question, so here is the deal

AVL tree has a time complexity of log(n) for inserting an element with n nodes inside the tree

so from your question, with a set of number (1,2,3,...,k) you wanted to insert, the time complexity would be like this

`summation from i=1 to i=k of log(i)` (i.e. log1 + log2 + log3 + ... + logk)

which is equals to

```
log(k!)
```

which is approximately equals to

`k*log(k)` (By using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation))

So to answer your question, it should be O(k log k) instead of O(k)